# Python ModuleNotFoundError of own modules (external anaconda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

So I have the infamous ModuleNotFoundError, and for a couple of hours I can't find the solution. I know that my project works in Pycharm but I wanted to set it up in Visual Studio Code.

the error

```
(base) C:\pythonprojects\AI_Project>C:/Users/quint/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/pythonprojects/AI_Project/be/kdg/MarkovDecisionProcess/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/pythonprojects/AI_Project/be/kdg/MarkovDecisionProcess/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import be.kdg.MarkovDecisionProcess.Agent as Agent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'be'
```

My project structure

```
project
|__be
   |__kdg
      |__MarkovDecisionProcess
         |__Agent.py
         |__Main.py
         |__Percept.py
```

in main.py

```
import be.kdg.MarkovDecisionProcess.Agent as Agent
import be.kdg.MarkovDecisionProcess.Percept as Percept 
import gym as gym
import numpy as np
...
```

in Agent.py

```
import gym
import numpy as np
from be.kdg.MarkovDecisionProcess.Percept import Percept

class Agent:
    def __init__(self, stateRewards, state_count, action_count):
    ...
```

my environment: Python 3.6.5 ('base':conda)

python path

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\quint\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
```

First I had __Init__.py in every dir, but then I read here http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html that this also could be an issue.

I will be alert for any suggestions and will try them as I read them.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to add `__init__.py` to your MarkovDecisionProcess to make it a module. Then, you have to add `\path\to\project` to `PYTHONPATH` for you to import.

For example, in Windows:

```
setx PYTHONPATH /M "\path\to\project"
```

In Unix/macOS:

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/project
```

Then, you can `import` like this: `from be.kdg.MarkovDecisionProcess import Agent`

Alternatively, you can use [`importlib.util`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to import Agent in Main.py just use

```
import Agent
```

because which is in the same directory

Comment: This will interpret but pylint recognizes it as an error in VS Code.